# Why does array copying in this way not assign digits to the target array?

Tags: c#

Why is this copying method not working? The target array should have digits greater than zero, tab2[0] = 3, tab2[1] = 4, etc.

```
int[] tab1 = { -2, 3, 4, - 5, 1, -7, -3, 4, 8, -10 };
int[] tab2 = new int[tab1.Length];
int a=0;
for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Length; i++)
{
    if (tab1[i]>0)
    {
        tab2[a] = tab1[i];
        a++;
    }                
    richTextBox1.AppendText(tab2[i] + " ");
}
```

but this work

```
foreach (var item in tab1)
            {
                if (item>0)
                {
                    tab2[a] = item;
                    a++;

                }

            }
```

Comment: What is the actual content of tab2 after the loop? What is `richTextBox1.AppendText(tab2[i] + " ");` supposed to do.

Comment: You set *5* items in the target array. The other 5 retain their original, default value. For integers, that's 0

Comment: I assume you wanted to append `tab2[a]` instead of `tab2[i]` - *before* you increment a of course...

Comment: Klaus Gütter "richTextBox1.AppendText"=  displays the contents of the table

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos 
I expected that tab2 [0] = 3, tab2 [1] = 4, tab2 [2] = 1, tab2 [3] = 4, tab2 [4] = 8 and the remaining elements will be equal to 0, but the whole array tab2 equals 0

Comment: No, it isn't. You are just using the wrong index...

Comment: `richTextBox1.AppendText(tab2[i] + " ");` should go outside of `for` loop...`richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(" ", tab2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this copying method not working?

Actually copying is working but the problem is with the last line within `for` loop. There you are using wrong index `i`. There is also the problem that you are initializing destination array with the `Length` of the source array. It might lead to the trailing zeros in the destination array. I do propose to use `List<int>` it will simplify your code...and also move last line outside of the loop

```
int[] tab1 = { -2, 3, 4, - 5, 1, -7, -3, 4, 8, -10 };
List<int> tab2 = new List<int>(tab1.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Length; i++)
{
    if (tab1[i]>0)
    {
        tab2.Add(tab1[i]);
    }                
}

richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(" ", tab2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] tab1 = { -2, 3, 4, - 5, 1, -7, -3, 4, 8, -10 };
int[] tab2 = new int[tab1.Length];
int a=0;
for (int i = 0; i < tab1.Length; i++)
{
    if (tab1[i]>0)
    {
        tab2[a] = tab1[i];
        richTextBox1.AppendText(tab2[a] + " ");
        a++;
    }
    //I'm not sure why you put this outside the if statement.
    //richTextBox1.AppendText(tab2[i] + " ");         
}
```